# Java Home not define (wso2ei-6.4.0 installation)

Tags: java, python, linux, wso2, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to install wso2ei-6.4.0, but it will not run due to the following error messages. I am running a RPi with Debian

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
 CARBON cannot execute java
```

I have executed Java -verison and have the following return

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I know the java directory, using Java -which

```
/usr/bin/java
```

How do I run Java from any of the directory to execute the installation of wso2ei-6.4.0?

Answer (score 1):

After some time and reading, I managed to add the following into `~/.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt"
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Note the arm32 directory for the jdk

Answer (score 0):

Try this (as root user):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

Does this solve your issue?

Comment: Which and where should I add this line, just confused where it would go?

Comment: You can start a terminal (or console) and launch this command, it should solve your problem.